# How to capture execution time of a Code Block call inside the function in c#

Tags: c#

I want to capture the execution time of a particular code block is that possible in c#

Example:

```
public class DoSomething
{
     public void Long_Running_Call()
     {
           .....
     }
     public void Medium_Running_Call()
     {
        .....
     }
 }
```

In the main function I want to know the execution time of **Long_Running_Call()** and **Medium_Running_Call()**.

```
public static void main()
{
    var do_something = New Do_Something();
    do_something.Long_Running_Call(); //I want to print the time taken for this   function call below
}
```

Comment: Use Stopwatch to measure the time

Comment: We can also use the Environment.TickCount and create a function that returns the execution time....                                                               public int ExecutionTime(Action func)
        {
            var start = Environment.TickCount;
            func();
            return Environment.TickCount - start;
        } ..... ExecutionTime(()=>do_something.Long_Running_Call()) will return the time taken to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
var do_something = new Do_Something();
watch.Start();                         // Start the timer
do_something.Long_Running_Call();      // Long running call
watch.Stop();                          // Stop the timer
TimeSpan elapsed = watch.Elapsed;
```

Of course, this is supposing `Long_Running_Call` is **synchronous** and blocking the main thread.

Comment: Yes the stop watch makes easier I used the Environment.TickCount to capture the time and created a function to do the changes like this public int StartWatch(Action func)
        {
            var start = Environment.TickCount;
            func();
            return Environment.TickCount - start;
        }

Comment: @SaravananVelappan `Environment.TickCount` is definitely a bad idea. Since `TickCount` property is of type `System.Int32`, the values will cycle between `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`. This means that it will cycle between negative and positive values every 25 days. If you start your program on one of those negative values days, then your logic `TickCount - start` will fail. Please see the important **Remarks** section on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I Agree Environment.TickCount is not a efficient way to capture the execution time